# How to get Axon event-identifier from the event-store

Tags: axon

Just a short question here...

by using Axon, we know that `AggregateLifecycle#apply(Object)` will be doing the event-sourced for us which under the hood going to persist our event into our event-store.

With regards to that matter, how to get the **event-identifier** (not the aggregate identifier) once we call that particular `apply` method ?

Thanks

Comment: Before writing up an answer, can you explain what the `messageIdentifier` is useful in your case? There might be some deviations from my reply based on this.

Comment: Hi @LucasCampos, thank you for your prompt response. I have a need to forward the same event to another message broker by using the same event identifier as what already persisted into the axon event store. 
Curently, i generated a new event id for that particular event, but i think ideally it should be using the same event id as what being originally stored in the event store..., that's why i'm asking this question. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your another answer, let me suggest you a way to follow.

The `MessageIdentifier` as used by AxonFramework (AF) is nothing more than an `UUID` generated for each `Message` you create.

Since you only need to reuse that info, you can pretty much get it from the `Message` while handling it. To make things easier for you, Axon provides a `MessageIdentifierParameterResolver` meaning you can simply use it in any `@MessageHandler` of you (of course, I am assuming you are using Spring as well).

Example:

```
@EventHandler 
public void handle(Event eventToBeForwarded, @MessageIdentifier String messageIdentifier) {
     // forward the event to another broker using the given `messageIdentifier`
}
```

Hope that helps you and make things clear!

Comment: Great to hear! Do not forget to mark the answer as accepted to help others as well =)